# Does a module exist for creating structured content in DotNetNuke?

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

Let’s say I have a site featuring a company’s various capabilities, each of those capabilities constituting a separate page. Every capability will feature a number of case studies, each of which is made up of an image, a title, a description and two or three other fields. These categorized case studies need to then be shown in various configurations on various pages throughout the site, on a rotator in one place, in a large list of all case studies somewhere else. Another example of this idea would be an employee directory. Every employee has a picture, a title, a phone number, etc. I would like to be able to set up the needed fields, enter in this data once, and then utilize this information in various locations across the site.

Does a component exist for DotNetNuke that will allow for the assembling and accessing of structured information in this way? In WordPress this would be done through custom fields and custom post types. In Drupal I would use something like CCK. How does DotNetNuke accomplish this task? I just need pointed in the right direction. With a little hacking I could probably repurpose a robust blogging module, like SunBlogNuke, and I’ve seen other modules that appear to do things somewhat similar to this, but I would hate to spend large amounts of client money casting around for a solution to what I would think is a fairly common challenge. How would this be best accomplished? Any guidance anyone could provide would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

yeah this is where DNN is very different then Drupal.  However this is solvable but not as elegantly as CCK/Views in Drupal.

Your Best Options:

- [Xmod](http://store.dotnetnuke.com/home/product-details/xmod-pro-30---forms-and-views-for-databases)
- [News Articles](http://www.ventrian.com/Products/Modules/NewsArticles.aspx)
- Built in Forms & Lists / XML (you need to do your own XSLT which is a bit of a pain)

I tend to use News Articles most often to solve this. You can drop the news articles module on page and that will serve as your main case study or portfolio repository. You can then configure it to collect custom fields.

It also has a module called Latest Articles - that you can drop on any page, and pull items from the main repository that are in a certain category, or with certain tags, and you can customize the HTML output. So if you know HTML/Javascript you can easily print the content to be in a photo gallery or something.

I haven't used XMod in awhile, but it's probably more flexible. But News Articles is pretty easy.

Comment: I just wanted to add a second recommendation for NewsArticles